# ModelState.Errors consist of empty strings

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

I am writing an MVC application with a form that has validation on it.

When I interrogate the errors, like this:

```
foreach (ModelState modelState in ViewData.ModelState.Values)
{
    foreach (ModelError error in modelState.Errors)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(error.ErrorMessage);
    }
}
```

the error messages returned in error.ErrorMessage is an empty string (""). I could easily write a little bit of code that validates if the error messages are all empty strings like this but that is a hack!

Does anyone know why this might be? The context is a form with some drop downs on it. The errors are returned if I select an item from one of the drop down inputs, but validates fine if these drop downs maintain their default state.

Thanks a lot, S

Comment: How are you setting up the validation? Is it attributes on properties in the model?

Comment: Check the member property and verify that there is a validation attribute with the ErrorMessage property set.

Comment: Show us the Model where you have provided the `ErrorMessage`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to validate a model, you must use **dataannotation** attributes like **[Required]**, do you use these annotations ? [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd901590(VS.95).aspx)

Then you must ensure that your property **ErrorMessage** is setted or - if you use external resource like resx file - your **ErrorMessageResourceType** & **ErrorMessageResourceName** [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.requiredattribute(v=vs.95).aspx)